# How to establish TLS connection between stunnel and Android app with my own certs from my CA

Tags: java, android, ssl, ssl-certificate, stunnel

I have [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/static/stunnel.html) running on my server with the following configuration:

```
[myservice]
accept = 12345
connect = 9999
verifyPeer = yes
cert = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
CAfile = /etc/stunnel/androidApp.crt
```

Both `cert` and `CAfile` has been issued by the same private CA.

I want to achieve a secure communication between stunnel (on port `12345`) and my Android application. Moreover, I want stunnel to verify the peer (that its certificate has been issued by the same CA as the stunnel's one) and on the other hand, the Android application should also verify the identity of the stunnel (server) part.

In my application I have the following code

```java
// ...
InputStream caInputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.android_app); //PKCS12
KeyStore keyStore;
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory;
SSLContext sslContext;
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory;
Socket socket;

keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keyStore.load(caInputStream, "password".toCharArray());

keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "password".toCharArray());

sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG"));

sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
socket = sslSocketFactory.createSocket("hostname", 12345);
// ...
```

When the socket is created, I get the following logs from stunnel:

```
2021.05.13 17:01:21 LOG5[2]: Service [myservice] accepted connection from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:YYYYY                                                                                          
2021.05.13 17:01:21 LOG6[2]: Peer certificate required
2021.05.13 17:01:25 LOG3[2]: SSL_accept: 1417C0C7: error:1417C0C7:SSL routines:tls_process_client_certificate:peer did not return a certificate                                          
2021.05.13 17:01:25 LOG5[2]: Connection reset: 0 byte(s) sent to TLS, 0 byte(s) sent to socket
```

At this stage I am fully aware that I am doing something fundamentally wrong (like I do not send the peer certificate), but I am a bit confused how to do that. Could you please give me a hand with this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is an assumption, but it looks like the PKCS12 file you are opening does not contain a private key.

Add private key -> create CSR -> sign with CA -> import chain to key store.

Everything else looks in order.

Comment: Thanks, but I do have the private key included in the PKCS12 file. I've double-checked it: one PKCS12 file was exported to a .p12 format with easy-rsa, the other one with openssl (like here: https://mkyong.com/linux/ssl-convert-pem-and-private-key-to-pkcs12/ ). None of these work.